# Angular.js for x do y for a do b

Tags: angularjs

How can I, in angular.js take a variable, that could either be 0 or 1, and anytime 0 is the value, make another variable that says Off, and for 1 make that same variable say On?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use the same variable, and ! one of them?

Comment: Please show use case. Variables in view and in controller/directive may be used differently. May only need one variable and not two

Comment: Doesn't really seem like an Angular question, but a fundamental javascript  misunderstanding. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else